# How to write a plsql stored procedure which can accept variable number of arguments of any datatype?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a stored procedure which can accept any number of inputs of any data type and then perform some operation.
To use variable no. Of inputs i could use table..but is there a general datatype in oracle?

Comment: [There is](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5A8C5AC6-BC32-4D78-B0DE-037162106C72).

Comment: Following up on @AlexPoole's comment, you might find [this page at ORACLE-BASE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/anydata) useful as an example of the use of the ANYDATA data type.